# Separate columns with different structure

Tags: r

I need to extract surname and city from the column.
Surname is always the first part of the column and then is ",".
City is the last part of the column and before it is "."
Raws don't have similar structure, so I want to extract the first part before the first comma and the last part before dot (.) and after the last space.

I tried:

```
df<-separate(df, Name, into=c("v1","v2", "v3", "v4"), sep=",")
```

v1 seems OK and it's a surname but I can't separate the city (the last part of the column)

Please help to separate surname as one column, city as another column.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHVYj.png)

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `tidyr::extract`, and specify two capture groups in the regex - one for surname (beginning of string, followed by a word) `(^\\w+\\b)`, the other for city (one or two words that follow a comma and a space (`,` ) followed by a literal dot (.) and the end of the string) `((?<=, )\\w+ *\\w+(?=\\.$))`:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% extract(Name, into = c("Surname", "City"), regex = "(^\\w+\\b).*((?<=, )\\w+ *\\w+(?=\\.$))",  remove = FALSE)
```

We can also extract the words (`\\w+`) into a list, then subset the `first` and `last` elements of the list (this will only work if cities have only one word each:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% mutate(output=str_extract_all(Name, "\\w+") %>%
        map(~list(surname=first(.x), city=last(.x))))%>%
        unnest_wider(output)
```

**output**

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Name                                  Surname City            
  <chr>                                 <chr>   <chr>           
1 Ivanov, Petr, Ivanovich, Novosibirsk. Ivanov  Novosibirsk     
2 Lipenko, Daria, Nizhniy Novgorod.     Lipenko Nizhniy Novgorod
```

**data**

```
df<-tibble(Name=c("Ivanov, Petr, Ivanovich, Novosibirsk.", "Lipenko, Daria, Nizhniy Novgorod."))
```

Comment: Thank you! I've 2 questions:
1. Some cities have two words (e.g. Nizhniy Novgorod) - will the function last(.x) work with these cases?
2. When I get a tibble after mutate, how is it possible to make it as dataframe again for further actions?

Comment: All operations on data.frames work on tibbles too. With time you will see tibbles are much cleaner and easier to use.

Comment: Now the extract answer works with cities with one or two words. See the updated answer.